# Why export intermediate results in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

[Google Earth Engine's coding best practice](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#export-intermediate-results) says to export intermediate results. It says

> Such large samples typically need to be exported. Do not expect such samples to be available interactively (for example through print()) or usable (for example as input to a classifier) without exporting them first.

But why?
And when it says not usable, does it mean that the result would be incorrect or the code can't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it mean that the result would be incorrect or the code can't run?

Code can't run. Specifically, the computation will time-out (after around 5 min). The guide recommends that intensive computations be done in steps, exporting the intermediate results, as exporting allows for a longer run time.

References: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging